# ftp through filezilla to google cloud machine, can't achieve it

Tags: ssh, ftp, vps, gcloud

before asking this question i looked through google and tried different alternatives none of which were successful for me, sadly. I'm a little above the noob level. What i want is to basicaly host a wordpress site on a google cloud debian machine.

I was doing good installing services through their SSH access until i got to the point where i installed an ftp service and wanted to access it through a remote computer(my own) i only got as far as to:

```
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 104.197.183.19...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@104.197.183.19" 22
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I kept on looking and trying new ways until i found the gcloud documentation for ftp but it is not aimed at new ones, so my questions are:

Where do i input the commands for gcloud, on my computer or on the SSH console(Google cloud machine)?
Do i need to use gcloud for ftp remote access or can i do it entirely through my computer and their SSH machine?
Do i really need to add an ssh authorization file to FileZilla or is there a way i can disable that check on my vps so it lets me sign in with just a username and a password?

- What i already tried and didn't work for me:

gCloud documentation for ssh and ftp
Google cloud documention for setting up a wordpress site
Many others

Basically what i need in short is to manage to access the vps through ftp so i can continue with my learning.. Been stuck there two days.

Comment: Transferring files to GCP Linux instances using `gcloud` command, file browsers, SCP tool, and WinSCP are described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

Answer (score 2):

To get access to a users public area, ie. public_html

Go to the accounts Cpanel area and under Security > SSH Access you can import a key file.

You can use PuttyGen to make one, you will need both a private and public key.
Past the keys into the box's.
You may get a warning message about the private key, this is ok.
Go to Manage under public key and authorize it.

Or

Make on using the interface in Cpanel and download both Keys.

Then in FileZilla

Host: IP of server
Protocol: SFTP
Logon Type: Key File
Key File: the PPK you made.
(if you asked Cpanel to make the file select the one that does not end in .pub and FileZilla will convert it for you to a .ppk file.

After clicking connect you should be in

If you still have an error make sure the SSH port (22) is open in your filewalls both Google cloud.google.com > Networks and WHM > LDF/CSF plugin

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH File Transfer Protocol.
No need to install ftp service.

Use winscp for connecting with sftp.

Comment: use wget to fetch files and mysql command line to handle database just another way of doing same :)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of transferring files to a Unix-based Google Compute Engine VM is via the `gcloud compute copy-files` command. For this, please install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). Then, run a command such as the following:

```
gcloud compute copy-files --zone=<Compute Engine zone>/path/to/local/file.txt <Compute Engine instance name>:/path/to/destination/file.txt
```

If you'd like to use FileZilla, you'll have to configure it for access. The SSH daemon on Compute Engine VMs is set up for key-based authentication. [This forum post](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=26406) indicates how this is possible in FileZilla. The catch is that you need to put your public key on the VM, which can be a little tricky. `gcloud compute copy-files` and `gcloud compute ssh` take care of this for you, which is why they are the recommended method.